# Is there any other option to decrease this piece of code time complexity?

Tags: c++, data-structures, graph, time-complexity

In this code, I'm iterating over a graph of vertices and comparing the weights of each vertex and its neighbors to find the maximum weight between them. Then store the number of times a vertex is marked by its neighbor vertices in `X[i]`.

```
map<double, list<double>> adjacency;
map<double, double> degree;
map<double, double> W;
map<double, double> X;

void find_max_w()
{
    double max = 0.;
    int idx_max;
    for (const auto &pair : adjacency)
    {
        max = 0;
        W.find(pair.first)->second > max ? max = W.find(pair.first)->second, idx_max = pair.first : max = max;
        for (double d : pair.second)
        {
            W.find(d)->second > max ? max = W.find(d)->second, idx_max = d : max = max;
        }
        X.find(idx_max)->second += 1;
    }
}
```

apparently, accessing to a map by value is time-consuming, and I have three of these :

```
W.find(pair.first)->second > max ? max = W.find(pair.first)->second, idx_max = pair.first : max = max;

W.find(d)->second > max ? max = W.find(d)->second, idx_max = d : max = max;

X.find(idx_max)->second += 1;
```

I was wondering if there is any other way to implement this more efficiently and less time-consuming? for example, other data structures?

Comment: You can try `unordered_map` instead of `map`. Whereas `map` is [usually] implemented as a balanced binary tree (or theoretically any other logarithmic search container), `unordered_map` is usually really a hash-table. hash-table gives you O(1) for search only in average, but it might beat what you get with a binary tree (O(logn)).

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Thanks. What I mean is that accessing the map is of log(n), I think. I'm calculating the time it takes to run my code, and accessing the map increases my total time. I wanted to use other data structures, such as o(1) of access to their element.

Comment: Don't abuse the poor misunderstood conditional expression like that. (It also adds an inefficiency from two `find`s.)

Comment: Why "map<double, double> X;"  This could be replace with "std::vector<int> X"  Same for degree.  W can be defined as "std::vector<double>" and the values looked up directly by the vertex index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider to replace one or more of your [**`std::map`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)s with [**`std::unordered_map`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)s.

The complexity for searching an item in `std::map`, using [`std::map::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) is:

> **Logarithmic** in the size of the container.

This is for *worse case* (since not mentioned otherwise).

On the other hand the complexity for searching an item in `std::unordered_map`, using [`std::unordered_map::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find) is:

> **Constant** on *average*, *worst case* **linear** in the size of the container.

(emphasis is mine)

The performance of both options depends on your data and must be profiled in order to select between them.
On average a search in an `unordered_map` is faster (**O(1)**), but there are cases it deteriorates to linear (**O(n)**). `map` is slower on average, but gives you stable performance (**O(logn)**).